# Looking for a solution to have more than 50+ filter values ​in Dashboard

Tags: configuration, dashboard, filters

I'm building a dashboard which will have Products as one of it's filters. And there are more than 10k different values while a standard dashboard filter can only allow 50 values. Is there any work around for this ? I guess we can use Tableau CRM but our clients aren't going to give us extra budget.

#Dashboard #Salesforce

Comment: If your clients aren't going to give you extra budget, then they'll be stuck with 50 values limit. With more than 10k values, having 50 in a list isn't going to work. If Tableau is too expensive, look into cheaper commercial or free/low-cost OSS BI/analytics products.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336682&type=1), Each dashboard can have up to 3 filters, and each filter can have up to 50 Dashboard Filter Options. Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GditbUAB/increase-dashboard-filter-limit-to-100-values) and vote for this feature.

As mentioned by identigral, See if you can use third party tools like Datapine, Power BI, Sisense etc., works for you.  However recommended would be using Tableau which has more benefits and features.

Thanks